# customizing assert macro

Tags: c++, windows, assert

On Windows/c++, I want to customize the assert dialog box to ignore an assertion forever, so I can be more aggressive with assertions.  I understand how hard it is to write a correct assert macro, and do not wish to do this, just hook the dialog code.  Is there an easy way (or concise hack) to do this?

[article on assert macro dangers](http://tinyurl.com/csgqbn) (googlecache)

update: more aggressive => use far more frequently and for noncrash **bugs**.  I want to be able to ignore an assertion forever so if a minor bug assertion occurs in a loop it doesn't effectively halt my process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the 
[_CrtSetReportHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yysf5e6(VS.80).aspx) function or the newer [_CrtSetReportHook2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94a21kwy(VS.80).aspx). You can use it to install a hook that remembers "seen" messages, and reports them as handled when seen again.

Answer (score 2):

If by "more aggressive" you mean using assertions for error handling, then you're better off using exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the teachings of our embedded master [Miro Samek](http://www.state-machine.com/resources/articles.php):

[An exception or a bug?](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401686)

Scroll down for customizing the behaviour of assert. (But do read everything else.)

Answer (score 0):

If the code doesn't need to be thread-safe, and if you only want to ignore the assertions "forever" in the sense that they will be ignored after the first time *each time* the program is run, and not forever in the sense that you ignore it the first time and after that it never fires again for *all* program runs, then just combine the assertion test with a static bool that's set to false by default.

```
void someFunc(...)
{
...
static bool bFireAssertion( false );

ASSERT( bFireAssertion || <your assertion test> );
...
}
```

then when you want it to stop firing, set bFireAssertion to true from within the debugger. Since it will always be true, the ASSERT will short-circuit and never evaluate your test anymore.

Comment: nice idea, but needs to be a checkbox in the gui.